# Convert an array of objects into a nested object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I have a JavaScript array of objects, like this:

```
var start = [{
  name: 'example name',
  nextItem: {}
},
{
  name: 'example name 2',
  nextItem: {}
},
{
  name: 'example name 3',
  nextItem: {}
}];
```

I want to convert this array into a single nested object, where the inner `nextItem` object of the first array item contains the whole object of the next array item. For example:

```
var output = {
  name: 'example name',
  nextItem: {
    name: 'example name 2',
    nextItem: {
      name: 'example name 3',
      nextItem: {}
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you already tried something, and do you stuck somewhere?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question shows input and expected output format but does not show any sign of effort. This is a requirement and not a problem statement.

Comment: @Rajesh already posted a simple solution to demonstrate how recursion works. As this is the first post from Daniel, he will be more precise next time. However, I also think, that a bit effort from the OP should be shown usually

Comment: @webdeb if that is true, we should close the post instead. If we answer such question, users get a habit of being spoon-fed and they do not search/try and just post requirements here.

Comment: @Rajesh - This question is perfectly valid.  You only need to show attempted code if you're asking what is wrong with it.  This is both a specific programming problem and a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development.  See here... https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Archer SO, in my understanding is a portal for Problem statements and not for requirement. So considering that, if a user just posts input and output, this is a requirement and not a problem statement. There are too many post on data manipulation. So simple google search should give a direction. May be not the best solution, but you should at least try something before posting a question. Hence, my vote.

Comment: @Rejesh if SO were so strict, 80% of questions would be closed. We should push on the OP like I did im my first comment, but close because the guy don't know where to start is a bit extreme

Comment: @webdeb This is an opinionated discussion. Not sure what is the best way to handle it but if OP is not sure where to begin with, and if we choose to answer, we should make it descriptive enough to help him and not just provide a working code.

Comment: @Rajesh - please read the link I gave you.  It explains why this question is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 2):

Could be done with a **recursive** function:

```
function nestItems(items) {
  var currentItem = items[0];
  if (!currentItem) return {};

  return {
     name: currentItem.name,
     nextItem: nestItems(items.slice(1))
  };
}


nestItems(start);
```

Comment: Should we really answer such question that do not show any sign of effort?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduceRight()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight).

Code:

```js
var start = [{name: 'example name',nextItem: {}},{name: 'example name 2',nextItem: {}},{name: 'example name 3',nextItem: {}}],
    output  = start.reduceRight(function (a, c) {
      return {
        name: c.name, 
        nextItem: a
      }; 
    });

console.log(output );
```

Updated based on comment from @NinaScholz

Comment: hm reverse? really? why not use `reduceRight`?

Comment: Code is first place for humans, so readability is on 1st place

Comment: Yeah, its not fair ik, the solution it self is ok, so upvote

Comment: I am totally agree that code should be in first place for humans. I have edited to make it more readable and better indented.. Thank you for your comments

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce on the array to add the objects:

```
function appendRec(obj, newObj) {
    if (obj || obj.nextItem === {}) obj.nextItem = newObj
    else appendRec(obj.nextItem, newObj)
    return obj
}

var output = start.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    return appendRec(acc, obj)
}, { nextItem: { } }).nextItem;
```

Comment: This will produce a single object with a single nextItem, which is the last one in the list..

Comment: Correct, please prefer Yosvel Quinteros answer.

Comment: I would prefer mine, is most elegant IMO :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var start = [{
  name: 'example name',
  nextItem: {}
},
{
  name: 'example name 2',
  nextItem: {}
},
{
  name: 'example name 3',
  nextItem: {}
}];

function concat(start) {
    var output = start[0];
    temp = output;
    for(i = 1;i < start.length;i ++) {
        temp.nextItem = start[i];
        temp = temp.nextItem;
    }
    return output;
}

console.log(concat(start));
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more graceful way of doing it, but this will do the trick.  (The trick being to start at the bottom and work your way up).

```js
var start = [{
  name: 'example name',
  nextItem: {}
},
{
  name: 'example name 2',
  nextItem: {}
},
{
  name: 'example name 3',
  nextItem: {}
}];

var output = {};

for (var i = start.length; i > 0; i--) {
  output = { name: start[i - 1].name, nextItem: output };
}

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Should we really answer such question that do not show any sign of effort?

Comment: @Rajesh - The question is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

You could use and take the returned accumulator as target for the nested object without mutating the original array.

```js
var start = [{ name: 'example name', nextItem: {} }, { name: 'example name 2', nextItem: {} }, { name: 'example name 3', nextItem: {} }],
    result = {};

start.reduce(function (o, a) {
    o.name = a.name;
    o.nextItem = {};
    return o.nextItem;
}, result);

console.log(result);
console.log(start);
```

ES6 with mutating the original array.

```js
var start = [{ name: 'example name', nextItem: {} }, { name: 'example name 2', nextItem: {} }, { name: 'example name 3', nextItem: {} }],
    result = {};

start.reduce(function (o, a) {
    Object.assign(o, a);
    return o.nextItem;
}, result);

console.log(result);
console.log(start);
```